# Do I still need to show a header if I'm just replicating the title of a tab?

Tags: navigation, web-app

I have a user management section in my CMS. The content is contained in 'tabs'. However as the title on each tab is basically the name of the page itself, do I need to still include a heading replicating that same title?

[image]

[image]

I feel like having the heading "Users" is pretty redundant, but semantically right.

Comment: You might need to make the "active" tab more prominent then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should (although it may be hidden in some scenarios). There are two things to consider:

## Mobile first

You are basing your design on the current presentation - that's a reasonable thing to do, so long you remember that the presentation might change on other devices, like, say, a mobile phone.

On a mobile phone the tabs may be collapsed under a menu, in which case they won't provide a visual indication to where the user is.

## Screenreader first

Again, you are basing your design on presentation. But one recommendation is to first design the content and structure of the interface (as would be read by a screen reader) only then deal with presentation.

In such a case, the menu may be skipped, so you'd still need the heading. What's more, blind people often search for headings. So there is an accessibility compliance involved here (you could have the heading on the page, but hidden - will still be read by screen readers).

Comment: I am definitely keeping mobile in mind. We are going to focus on that in the second iteration. This is not a public application and will not be used by blind folks, but I still think the consideration is important. Thanks for your feedback!